# How to enable language extensions / pragmas project wide by default?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

Is there a way to put `{-# LANGUAGE <feature> #-}` pragmas in either the:

- `<project>.cabal`, or
- `stack.yaml`

file, to avoid repeating the same header code in every **.hs* file of a project?

Comment: `default-extensions:` field in Cabal

Comment: @user2407038, I think any mention of that feature should probably also explain why many people (such as myself) are generally opposed. It makes it impossible to see from the text of each module which extensions are in play. That can be quite confusing!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @user2407038 said in the comments, you can use the [`default-extensions`](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#pkg-field-default-extensions) field in your `<project>.cabal` file.

If you wanted to have `OverloadStrings` and `GADTs` in all of your modules in the project, you would list it in relevant section of your cabal file (i.e. if you want it for all of your library files, put it in library).

For example:

```
-- <project>.cabal
...
library
  hs-source-dirs:       src
  default-extensions:   GADTs
                      , OverloadedStrings 
  ...
```

If you are using a `package.yaml` configuration file to generate your `<project>.cabal` file, you can also specify this field there.

```
-- package.yaml
library:
  source-dirs: src
  default-extensions:
    - OverloadedStrings
    - GADTs
  exposed-modules:
    - MyModule
  ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Wow this is annoying. The error message from cabal literally says to use 'extensions:', but you have to use 'default-extensions:'...